# How can I send an object to a Servlet from a JSP via hyperlink?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

How can I send a an object got it from a bean in a JSP page to a Servlet after clicking an hyperlink??

something like...

```
...
<td align="center"><% if(j.getClubActual().isIsResource()){ request.setAttribute("equipo", j.getClubActual());%>
<a href="teamServlet" type="submit" target="_blank"><%= j.getClubActual().getNombre()%></a><%}%>
</td>
...
```

But when I try to recover it in the teamServlet, the request object is empty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifetime of a HTTP request ends when its associated HTTP response is finished sending the data (read: the HTML page generated by JSP). Clicking a link will create a brand new HTTP request which doesn't contain the attributes of any previous request at all.

You need to send the unique identifier of the Java object in question as a request parameter. Ultimately, the HTML must end up to basically look like this:

```html
<a href="teamServlet?clubId=123">link</a>
```

In the servlet, you can get the request parameter as follows:

```
String clubId = request.getParameter("clubId");
```

You can use this value to re-obtain the Java object associated with the given ID from some data store.

```
Club club = clubService.find(Long.valueOf(clubId));
// ...
```

Comment: But sending the object as a request parameter, you are invoking the doGet from the Servlet however if you want to use a Post method to hide the parameter, how could I do it?

Comment: Use a `<form method="post">` with `<input type="hidden">` and `<input type="submit">` instead. Keep in mind that this breaks crawlability by searchbots and bookmarkability by endusers.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with that will break the crawlability by searchbots and bookmarkability?? I'm learning Jave EE now, and I'm a newbie...

Comment: A POST request is not indexed by searchbots like Google (so if it for example leads to some product detail page, it won't come up in any search results), also the enduser can't bookmark the resulting URL in order to reproduce exactly the same request.

Comment: After setting the <form> with the correct content, how could i change the appearance of the submit button, in order to look like a hyperlink ?? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Throw in some CSS or use a plain link which submits the form by JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

What object you are trying to send?

If you want to "send" objects, I think your safest bet is to use HTTP session to do that. You can't send "objects" (or beans) with a hyperlink to a servlet. You can only send parameters values usually in form of strings.